# R: Looping through multiple columns and using all columns in a function?

Tags: r

In R: How do I loop through multiple columns and use a custom made function that takes in an argument from each of those columns and modifies those columns accordingly?

For example I have the following dataframe:

```
> head(runTimeSep)
  hours   h minutes  min
1    70 min      NA <NA>
2    21 min      NA <NA>
3   106 min      NA <NA>
4    75 min      NA <NA>
5    14 min      NA <NA>
6    82 min      NA <NA>
7     1 h        11 min
```

my goal is to obtain a list of total minutes in the hours column.  If "1h" is listed in the hours and h column, then convert hours to minutes and add on the minutes from the minutes column (or add nothing is it's a perfect hour with NA in the minutes column).

Therefore I have created the following function to apply to the dataframe:

```
# convert hours to minutes function
hoursToMins = function(hours, h, minutes, min) {
  if (h == 'h' && min == "min") {
    (hours = as.numeric(hours)*60+as.numeric(minutes))
  }
  if (h=="h" && min != "min") {
    (hours = as.numeric(hours)*60)
  }
}
```

How do I apply this function across all columns in the data frame?  Eg. with lapply, ddpply, etc.

Edit: I also attempted the following:

```
finalRunTime = ifelse(runTimeSep$h == "h", runTimeSep$hours*60,               runTimeSep$hours)
head(finalRunTime)  
runTimeSep$hours = finalRunTime
```

which worked fine. But when I tried to apply the second round of ifelse:

```
finalRunTime = ifelse(runTimeSep$min == "min", runTimeSep$hours +  runTimeSep$minutes, runTimeSep$hours)
head(finalRunTime)
runTimeSep$hours = finalRunTime
```

the 2nd round causes the else case (if there's no minute column) to become NA. Please help. Thanks.

In response to @Sandipan's answer:
How do I use which to discriminate whether the min column is 'min' or NA?
I tried:

```
indices <- which(runTimeSep$h == 'h' && runTimeSep$min != 'min')
runTimeSep[indices,]$hours <- 60*runTimeSep[indices, ]$hours

indices <- which(runTimeSep$h == 'h' && runTimeSep$min == 'min')
runTimeSep[indices,]$hours <- 60*runTimeSep[indices, ]$hours + 
  runTimeSep[indices,]$minutes
```

However both sets of indices returned empty sets.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, I posted my response in the edit above for easier readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you a vector of minutes by row and if you wanted its total, then just wrap `sum()` around it:

```
with( dat,   (h=="h")*60*hours + (h=="min")*hours + 
                                             ifelse( is.na(minutes), 0, minutes) )

[1]  70  21 106  75  14  82  71
```

It substitutes 0 for NA when minutes is NA. When a new column with those values is desired you can do this:

```
 dat$newmins <- with( dat, (h=="h")*60*hours + (h=="min")*hours + 
                                             ifelse( is.na(minutes), 0, minutes) )
```

Comment: thanks, it seems to work, however it seems to have missing entries.  eg. what corresponds to index 95 in the data frame is actually index 92 in the vector.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I realized that this is due to that certain rows had to be removed from the data frame prior to applying this function.  So how do we get the vector to match up with the dataframe's indices?

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding what was done. This could have been used as `dat$newmins <- with( dat,   (h=="h")*60*hours + (h=="min")*hours +  ifelse( is.na(minutes), 0, minutes) )` and the lengths of all terms in the expression would be guaranteed to match the number number of rows in the dataframe.

Comment: thank you very much.  It seems to have worked very nicely!

Answer (score 0):

you want something like this:

```
indices <- which(runTimeSep$h == 'h')
runTimeSep[indices,]$hours <- 60*runTimeSep[indices, ]$hours + 
                              runTimeSep[indices,]$minutes
```